# most efficient vba method to copy data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am just trying a simple copy from one Excel sheet to another but the program seems to be taking forever.

```
n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(WAEnv.Range("a4:a" & WAEnv.Rows.Count))
ro = 3

For i = 4 To n + 4
    If Len(Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 1).Value)) > 0 Then
       ro = ro + 1
       WAPatch.Cells(ro, 1).RowHeight = WAEnv.Cells(i, 1).RowHeight
       WAPatch.Cells(ro, 1).Value = Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 1).Value)
       WAPatch.Cells(ro, 2).Value = Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 2).Value)
       WAPatch.Cells(ro, 3).Value = Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 3).Value)
       WAPatch.Cells(ro, 4).Value = Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 4).Value)
       WAPatch.Cells(ro, 5).Value = Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 5).Value)
    End If
Next i
```

Is there a faster or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Filter and then copy visible cells perhaps instead of going line by line.

Comment: i need all the data though i.e. all rows not filtered rows.

Comment: Your `If` statement should theoretically exclude rows, depending on your data, so I'm not sure what you mean by that. You could also read the data into a variant array and manipulate it there, then write to the other worksheet in one step. Repeatedly reading from/writing to a sheet is slow.

Comment: Yep agree, I am looking to see if the first column of each row has data , if yes , then proceeding with the copying

Comment: You can filter out blanks...

Comment: @BigBen while trying simple lines like `Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy WAPatch.Range("A3")` with a filtered range of 150 K rows. it gives 1004 error "Ms excel cannot create or use data range reference because too complex. Obviously it is working with small data range. May please direct too some enlightenment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If objective to set `RowHeight` could be sacrificed, then may try the following code (obviously after modifying sheets, ranges particulars to your requirement)

```
Sub test()
Dim WAEnv As Worksheet, WAPatch As Worksheet, Rng As Range
Dim SrcArr As Variant, DstArr() As Variant
Dim Rw As Long, cl As Range
Dim Xrow As Long, Xcol As Long, Lastrow As Long
Dim Chunk60K As Long
Dim tm As Double
tm = Timer

Set WAEnv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set WAPatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

Set Rng = WAEnv.Range("A4:E" & WAEnv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
SrcArr = Rng.Value
Xrow = 1
Chunk60K = 0

    For Rw = 1 To UBound(SrcArr, 1)
        If SrcArr(Rw, 1) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve DstArr(1 To 5, 1 To Xrow)
            For Xcol = 1 To 5
            DstArr(Xcol, Xrow) = SrcArr(Rw, Xcol)
            Next Xcol

            If Xrow = 60000 Then  ' To Overcome 65K limit of Application.Transpose
            WAPatch.Range("A" & Chunk60K * 60000 + 3).Resize(UBound(DstArr, 2), UBound(DstArr, 1)).Formula = Application.Transpose(DstArr)
            Chunk60K = Chunk60K + 1
            Xrow = 1
            ReDim DstArr(1 To 5, 1 To 1)
            Debug.Print "Chunk: " & Chunk60K & " Seconds Taken: " & Timer - tm
            Else
            Xrow = Xrow + 1
            End If

        End If
    Next Rw


WAPatch.Range("A" & Chunk60K * 60000 + 3).Resize(UBound(DstArr, 2), UBound(DstArr, 1)).Formula = Application.Transpose(DstArr)
Debug.Print "Completed at Chunk: " & Chunk60K & " Total Seconds Taken: " & Timer - tm

End Sub
```

Code takes around 7-8 seconds to process around 300 K rows (around 1/2 of it filtered out)

Since I personally don't prefer to keep calculations, event processing and screen updating off (in normal cases) i haven't added that standard lines. However you may use these standard techniques, depending on the working file condition.

Edit: adding code including Row height setting  (unstable after 150 K)

```
Sub test4()
Dim WAEnv As Worksheet, WAPatch As Worksheet, Rng As Range
Dim SrcArr As Variant, DstArr() As Variant
Dim Rw As Long, cl As Range
Dim Xrow As Long, Xcol As Long, Lastrow As Long
Dim Chunk60K As Long
Dim tm As Double
tm = Timer


Set WAEnv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set WAPatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
'n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(WAEnv.Range("a4:a" & WAEnv.Rows.Count))

Lastrow = WAEnv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print Lastrow
Xrow = 1
Chunk60K = 0

        For Rw = 4 To Lastrow
        Set Rng = WAEnv.Range("A" & Rw & ":E" & Rw)
        If Rng(1, 1).Value > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve DstArr(1 To 5, 1 To Xrow)
        Xcol = 1
            For Each cl In Rng.Columns.Cells
            DstArr(Xcol, Xrow) = cl.Value
            Xcol = Xcol + 1
            Next cl
        WAPatch.Cells(Xrow, 1).RowHeight = Rng(1, 1).RowHeight

            If Xrow = 60000 Then  ' To Overcome 65K limit of Application.Transpose
            WAPatch.Range("A" & Chunk60K * 60000 + 3).Resize(UBound(DstArr, 2), UBound(DstArr, 1)).Formula = Application.Transpose(DstArr)
            Chunk60K = Chunk60K + 1
            Xrow = 1
            ReDim DstArr(1 To 5, 1 To 1)
            Debug.Print "Chunk: " & Chunk60K & " Seconds Taken: " & Timer - tm
            Else
            Xrow = Xrow + 1
            End If
      End If
      Next Rw


WAPatch.Range("A" & Chunk60K * 60000 + 3).Resize(UBound(DstArr, 2), UBound(DstArr, 1)).Formula = Application.Transpose(DstArr)
Debug.Print "Completed at Chunk: " & Chunk60K & " Total Seconds Taken: " & Timer - tm

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way we can copy over formatting with the above code as well? This works heaps faster than the previous code. Almost instantaneously copying rows.

Comment: before posting I tried with 150 K rows and Row height setting. and it worked at around 10 minutes. but when tried with 300 k it is becoming  unstable. If your requirement is below 150 K row I would be happy to share that code.

Comment: Sorry i skipped trimming in your code. May use `DstArr(Xcol, Xrow) = Trim(SrcArr(Rw, Xcol))`

Comment: requirement is much less than that . Max 10k rows.

Comment: Edit Code with 2nd option, May pl  feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(WAEnv.Range("a4:a" & WAEnv.Rows.Count))
ro = 3

For i = 4 To n + 4
    If Len(Trim(WAEnv.Cells(i, 1).Value)) > 0 Then
        ro = ro + 1
        WAEnv.range("A" & i & ":E" & i).copy
        WAPatch.range("A" & ro & ":E" & ro).pastespecial xlpastevalues
        With WAPatch.range("A" & ro & ":E" & ro)
            .Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & .Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & .Address & ")))")
        End With
    End if
Next
```

Copy and past the row of data in one go then trim the resulting data.

Also if you have a large number of formulas in the sheet it will slow down as it recalculates, if this is the case you can try setting calcs to manual at the start of your code and back to auto at the end.

Comment: I tried the code above, this seems to be executing slower than the initial code.

Comment: Did you turn calculations off?

Comment: the sheet doesn't have any formulas currently

Answer (score 0):

I'd experiment with the times achieved without looping at all. Copy the entire sheet across, and then on the new sheet sort by one column descending to put your blanks to the bottom. If you care about the sort order then shrink your range and sort them again.

Admittedly that might not be quicker, but if you don't need the rows sorted as they originally were then you'll only need the one sort.

Finally, if you have a high proportion of blanks, and you're not coming back to the original sheet, do the sorting there before copying. Or apply a filter and delete the offending rows, though I find this a little more finicky.